# How can part of JComponent be obscured from Mouseevents? E.g. some region of JButton not reacting, rest is fine

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcomponent

This issue cost me a lot of time to identify, now I am curious what causes this strange behaviour:

In the example, There is a JFrame class which displays a JPanel "page" which itself gets a reference to the "parent" JFrame.
My mistake was to do that in the process of constructing the objects.

What is stunning is that in some cases, the reaction of JComponents on the "page" (like JButtons, JRadioButtons, JCHeckboxes etc.), which some times reacted to the mouse just fine, sometimes not at all, and sometimes only a fraction of the surface was working.

So I tried to isolate this in a minimum example below, which I could demonstrate on JRE 1.8, JRE12 and JRE13 on both Windows 7 x64 and Windows 10 x64.

In order to reproduce, you might need to play with the button size vs. `JFrame.setSize()`.
The behaviour on my systems is, that the button reacts very well to the mouse with some animation on `mouseEntered`, and a click with the mouse will fire the `ActionEvent`.
**But not in a fixed-size area in the bottom right of the button**. If you go there with the mouse, no event will be fired.
The size of that "dead" region remains constant under changes of windows size and component size, as you can try out with different `LayoutManagers`in the "page" code.

The same applies for other JComponents that fire events.

My question is: why is there a problem with the ActionListening-System. It would be intuitive, if the Listening would either be entirely broken or not at all.

From the answer I hope to learn more about the inside of the mouse event-generation in JComponents so as to be more vigilant in my programs of the future.

Here is the main JFRame:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TESTFRAME extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TESTFRAME();
            }
        });
    }

    public TESTFRAME() {
        super("TESTFRAME");
        PAGE page = new PAGE();
        /*
         * the following line causes very strange behaviour!
         */
        page.setParent(this);

    
        JPanel DISPLAY = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        DISPLAY.add(page);
        add(DISPLAY);
        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

FYI check also what happens when comment out the line `page.setParent(this);`.

and this is the "page" to be displayed in the frame:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PAGE extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public TESTFRAME parent = null;

    public PAGE() {
        // !!! activate the following line setting the GridLayout, to make button large
        // in the bottom right corners, I continue not being able to click
        // setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        JButton bt_large = new JButton("<html><br>large close button<br><br></html>");
        bt_large.addActionListener(this);
        add(bt_large);

        JButton bt_small = new JButton("small button");
        bt_small.addActionListener(this);
        add(bt_small);
    }

    public TESTFRAME getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(TESTFRAME parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("button click received!");
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: Don't use all capitals for class name and variable names. Follow Java conventions.

Comment: @camickr: you are absolutely right, sorry. Breaches of convention come from reworking the code to get minimal. I will be stricter next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `getParent()` is a method of the `Component` class.

By implementing you own method default functionality is lost, causing the problems you are experiencing.

Try renaming your methods to `getParentFrame()` and `setParentFrame()` to see the normal behaviour.

However, you don't even need those methods. Instead you can access the parent frame of the panel by using methods from the JDK.

In your `ActionListener` you can have code like:

```
Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( this );
window.dispose();
```

Comment: wow, thank you!
accidental overriding did not occur to me, but makes perfect sense!
I have lost a lot of time with this issue, and understanding it is very valuable since it removes the fear of getting trapped again.
Thank you also for the hint to SwingUtilities!